# How to set an API Key's "key description" of an Azure AD Registered App

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to figure out a way to set the **key description** of an Azure AD App (Registered App) either via Azure CLI, or PowerShell

I know i can create the API Access key, using az ad app update --id --password, or --key-value, but there is no way to set the description, so i can name the key

Is there any way to create the description for the Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For those interested, here is the solution to my question:**

Using Powershell, you can programmatically set the "Description",aka the Name, for the App Password, in the API Permissions of the AAD Registered Application using the following property of the "New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential" command:

-CustomKeyIdentifier

**Here is a complete command for visibility:**

```
$app = "EnterYourAADRegisteredAppName"
$aadAppId = (Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$app'").ObjectId
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $aadAppId -CustomKeyIdentifier
"EnterDesiredAppPasswordName"
```

Comment: This did not appear to work for me. The provided identifier appears in the CustomKeyIdentifier property of the credential object in PS, albeit as an array of bytes rather than a string, but it does not show up when the credentials are viewed in the AAD portal. Conversely, names provided for keys created with the portal do not appear in the PS credential object

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create the description via powershell or cli, you can just do that in the portal.

The [AAD powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#applications) and [cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest) essentially call the [AAD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog), the `passwordCredentials` does not has the `passwordDescription` property, see [PasswordCredential Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#passwordcredential-type). So you will find even if you get the application via powershell or cli, the result will not return the `passwordCredentials` with `passwordDescription`.

In the portal, if you create a key and catch the request, you will find it calls the api `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/xxxxx?expand={expand}&getLogoUrl={getLogoUrl}`, it is a Microsoft undisclosed api. You can see the `passwordDescription` in the response.

[image]

Comment: Are there any tricks to consume those undisclosed APIs, or is it straightforward?